# How Get configurationVal of Packing_charge in below JSON?

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

This is the url I used to fetch 
    private static String url = "http://52.206.14.188:8080/Configuration";
But I can't able to get the Packing charge value someone help me to write code to parse I am beginner to android

```
 [
      {
        "configurationId": 1,
        "configurationName": "CGST",
        "configurationVal": "2.5"
      },
      {
        "configurationId": 2,
        "configurationName": "SGST",
        "configurationVal": "2.5"
      },
      {
        "configurationId": 3,
        "configurationName": "DELIVERY_CHARGE",
        "configurationVal": "0"
      },
      {
        "configurationId": 4,
        "configurationName": "Admin_Mobile",
        "configurationVal": "9500100042,8939404592"
      },
      {
        "configurationId": 5,
        "configurationName": "MIN_ORDER_AMOUNT",
        "configurationVal": "98"
      },
      {
        "configurationId": 6,
        "configurationName": "Packing_charge",
        "configurationVal": "3"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  String myjsonstring = "http://52.206.14.188:8080/Configuration";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    try
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myjsonstring);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject currentobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String configurationId = currentobject.getString("configurationId");
            String configurationName = currentobject.getString("configurationName");
            String configurationVal = currentobject.getString("configurationVal");

            Log.i("configurationId", ":" + configurationId);
            Log.i("configurationName", ":" + configurationName);
            Log.i("configurationVal", ":" + configurationVal);

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setText(configurationId);
            tv.setText(configurationName);
            tv.setText(configurationVal);


        }


    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How to print it in a textView